How to return the subarray of a smallest sum contiguous subarray and not the sum?
I am working on a fairly simple and popular smallest sum contiguous subarray problem in java. The problem asks to create a class, and in it write a method that takes an integer array and returns the smallest sum contiguous subarray. A sample array such as {3, -4, 2, -3, -1, 7, -5} should return: {-4, 2, -3, -1}, because its sum is -6, and there is not a subarray in the sample array with a smaller sum than -6. There are several tutorials for this problem found online, like at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-sum-contiguous-subarray/#, but these solutions return the sum and not the entire subarray created from the original array. I'm trying to find out how to return the subarray.
This is the code I have so far:
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array1[] = { 3, -4, 2, -3, -1, 7, -5 };
        int size1 = array1.length;

        int array2[] = { 1, 2, -1, 3, -6, -1, 4, 5 };
        int size2 = array2.length;

        int array3[] = { 10, -8, 3, -7, 2, -3 };
        int size3 = array3.length;

        System.out.println(smallestSum(array1, size1));
        System.out.println(smallestSum(array2, size2));
        System.out.println(smallestSum(array3, size3));
    }

    static String smallestSum(int array[], int size) {
        int smallEnding = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int smallCurrent = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        ArrayList<Integer> subArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            if (smallEnding > 0) {
                smallEnding = array[i];
            } else {
                smallEnding += array[i];
                subArray.add(array[i - 1]);
            }

            smallCurrent = Math.min(smallCurrent, smallEnding);
        }

        return ("The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is " +
                subArray.toString() + " with a sum of "
                + Integer.toString(smallCurrent));
    }
}

This is the output I get:
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-4, 2, -3, -1] with a sum of -6
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-1, -6, -1, 4] with a sum of -7
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-8, 3, -7, 2] with a sum of -13

I have worked out how find the smallest sum contiguous subarray and can return the sum correctly, but the returned subarrays are not correct. The subarray is correct for array1, but not correct for array2 and array3 (array2 should read [-1, -6], and array3 should read [-8, 3, -7, 2, -3]). I'm having trouble figuring out why this works for array1 but not for the others. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

The issue is with how you are not correctly tracking the start of the newest subarray and therefore updating the elements in a manner that doesn't correspond to the actual subarray with the smallest sum.
To fix it, you can store the start and end indices of the subarrays. There may be multiple found, so you need to:

keep track of the current starting index (where the current subarray begins)
update the actual start and end indices whenever you find a smaller sum.

Then, you can add the elements from the start to the end of the correct subarray to your subArray list.
Edited to include the rest of your code.
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array1[] = { 3, -4, 2, -3, -1, 7, -5 };
        int size1 = array1.length;

        int array2[] = { 1, 2, -1, 3, -6, -1, 4, 5 };
        int size2 = array2.length;

        int array3[] = { 10, -8, 3, -7, 2, -3 };
        int size3 = array3.length;

        System.out.println(smallestSum(array1, size1));
        System.out.println(smallestSum(array2, size2));
        System.out.println(smallestSum(array3, size3));
    }

    static String smallestSum(int array[], int size) {
        int smallEnding = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int smallCurrent = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        int currentStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int actualStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int end = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        ArrayList<Integer> subArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        
            // this happens each time we start a new subarray
            if (smallEnding > 0) {
                smallEnding = array[i];
                // therefore `i` must be the newest starting index
                currentStart = i; 
            } else {
                smallEnding += array[i];
            }
        
            // current subarray sum becomes smaller, so we
            // need to update the actual start and end indices
            if (smallEnding < smallCurrent) {
                actualStart = currentStart;
                end = i;
            }
            
            smallCurrent = Math.min(smallCurrent, smallEnding);
        }
    
        // add the elements to the ArrayList
        for (int i = actualStart; i <= end; i++) {
            subArray.add(array[i]);
        }
        
        return ("The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is " +
                    subArray.toString() + " with a sum of "
                    + Integer.toString(smallCurrent));
    }
}


This code gives me the following output:
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-4, 2, -3, -1] with a sum of -6
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-6, -1] with a sum of -7
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-8, 3, -7, 2, -3] with a sum of -13


This program finds the contiguous subarray with the smallest sum for three different arrays.
It uses a variation of Kadane's algorithm, but instead of finding the maximum subarray sum, it looks for the minimum subarray sum.
The issue is you are not properly tracking the start of the newest subarray
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array1[] = { 3, -4, 2, -3, -1, 7, -5 };
        int size1 = array1.length;

        int array2[] = { 1, 2, -1, 3, -6, -1, 4, 5 };
        int size2 = array2.length;

        int array3[] = { 10, -8, 3, -7, 2, -3 };
        int size3 = array3.length;

        System.out.println(smallestSum(array1, size1));
        System.out.println(smallestSum(array2, size2));
        System.out.println(smallestSum(array3, size3));
    }

    static String smallestSum(int array[], int size) {
        int minSoFar = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxEndHere = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end= 0;
        int temp=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> subArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            maxEndHere += array[i];
            if(minSoFar>maxEndHere) {
                minSoFar=maxEndHere;
                start=temp;
                end=i;
            }
            if(maxEndHere>0) {
                maxEndHere=0;
                temp = i+1;
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
            subArray.add(array[i]);
        }

        return ("The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is " +
                subArray.toString() + " with a sum of "
                + Integer.toString(minSoFar));
    }
}

This code gives the following output:-
The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-4, 2, -3, -1] with a sum of -6

The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-6, -1] with a sum of -7

The smallest sum contiguous subarray of the array is [-8, 3, -7, 2, -3] with a sum of -13

